# Xcode build settings, environment variables for simulator vs device

Tags: ios, xcode

I’m building an iOS app (in Swift, not that it makes any difference). It talks to a basic REST API.

When building for the simulator, I have it hitting my local server at http://localhost:8000

When building for the device, I would like it to hit a public test server at http://somedomainorother.com

I know there are ways to build environment variables for debug vs release, but is there a way to write based on the build target as well?

Answer (score 1):

I made a pod to handle environment settings, you can take a look at it here: https://github.com/nebiros/JIMEnvironments.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. If there’s a “more correct” way to wing it, I’m all ears.

```
    #if  (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        static let Path = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/"
    #else
        static let Path = "http://somedomain.com/api/v1/"
    #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR and TARGET_OS_IPHONE is better.

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    static let Path = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/"
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    static let Path = "http://somedomain.com/api/v1/"
#endif
```